# Remove duplicate lines from file txt using php

Tags: php, duplicates, lines

I have a textfile containing:

```
name : id : phone    
Ahmed : 1 : 972258522    
Ali : 2 : 741852933    
Jack : 5 : 741852963    
Ahmed : 77 : 85296    
mia : 7852 : 8888888    
Jack : 77 : 9999999
```

i want to remove duplicate line that have the same name i need the output as :

```
Ahmed : 1 : 972258522   
Ali : 2 : 741852933    
Jack : 5 : 741852963    
mia : 7852 : 8888888
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Start with some code, it's always good

Comment: Create an array for names; loop through the file one line at a time; extract name from the line; if name isn't in the names array, put it in the array and write the line; continue till end of file

Comment: i was use this code put i have get error  
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $lines = array_intersect_key($lines, array_unique(array_map(function($v){
        return trim(explode(":", $v)[0]);
    }, $lines)));

    print_r($lines);

?> 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\index.php on line 6
iam using php 5.3